# C# - data process

Tags: c#, numbers, substring, cycle

I am new to C# and I am working with a .csv file which contains a lot of row just like this:

```
 2014.02.02.;Name;Adress;Ft;24,32,46,13,15
 2014.02.03.;Name;Adress;Ft;12,30,42,19,11,18
 2014.02.03.;Name;Adress;Ft;61,32,44,42,22,17
 2014.02.04.;Name;Adress;Ft;76,43,42,11,14 ....
```

Every line is similar, except the fact that after the "Ft;" there are 5 OR 6 numbers randomly.

I have written an application which reads the .CSV file and list it on the console.

Now all I need is to gather ONLY the numbers from the end of each line (which can be 5 or 6) and list only those to the console as new lines. (so the outfit would not change only the content)

I was not able to write this cycle, because the numbers of the number always changing randomly (5 or 6) and I am not sure how could I do that but I guess I need to use the substring.

Could you help me out with it? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please show the code you have so far

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
var lines = File.ReadAllLines("Input.txt");

foreach (string line in lines)
{
    var splitBySemiColon = line.Split(';');
    List<int> numbersAtEnd = splitBySemiColon
        .Last()
        .Split(',')
        .Select(s => int.Parse(s))
        .ToList();

    //do whatever you need to with numbersAtEnd... perhaps: foreach (int i in numbersAtEnd) Console.WriteLine(i)


}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (var row in rows)
{
     var lineElements = row.Split(';');
     var numbers = lineElements.Last();
     var lastNumber = numbers.Split(',').Last();
     Console.WriteLine(lastNumber);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
StreamReader sr=new Streameader("myFile.csv");

List<int> myNumbers=new List<int>();
using (sr)
{
  while (!sr.EndOfStream)
   {
      string line=sr.Readline();
      int index=line.LastIndexoF(';');
      string numbers=sr.Substring(index+1,sr.Length-1-index);
      string[] num=numbers.Split(',');
      foreach (string n in num)
      {
        myNUmbers.Add(int.Parse(n));
      }

   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var Lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"c:\file.csv").Select( x => x.Split(';')).ToList();
Lines.ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(string.Join("\t", x.Last().Split(','))));
```

output in console:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you sre storing each line in a string variable and there is a consistency as you have mentioned then following is the simplest way

```
   string line = "2014.02.02.;Name;Adress;Ft;24,32,46,13,15";

   string numbers = line.Substring(line.LastIndexOf(';') + 1);
```